# Driving piezo scanner tubes using the driven internal electrode configuration

Tags: driver, polarity, piezo, piezoelectricity

I'm planning on doing a project involving a piezo tube scanner (PTS). The PTS will be used for 3 axis manipulation of a sharp needle. [PiezoDrive](https://www.piezodrive.com/actuators/piezoelectric-tube-scanners/) has a few scanners and some info on how to use them. Among that info is a description of how to drive a PTS using a "driven internal electrode configuration". The image below is included in that description.

[image]

The description mentions that "Care must be taken not to apply **positive voltages** to the internal electrode since this can lead to depolarisation". I'm guessing that this is why In5 spans from 0 to -10V, unlike In1 and In3. My problem with this is that there might still be cases where the PTS sees a positive voltage on the inner electrode.

For example, Out1 and Out2 could have a voltage of +25V and -25V respectively, (1V at In1), and Out5 a **negative voltage** of -2.5V, (-1V at In5). But wouldn't that create a **positive voltage** between Out5 and Out2? (-2.5V - (-25V) = +22.5V). According to the quote, that should be avoided.

Is this a problem or am I missing something? I hope my question is understandable. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: @Andy
Thank you for your answer! Yes, applying -250V to the internal electrode would prevent positive voltage, but I would like to use the internal electrode for Z manipulation, which seems impossible if it sits at a constant voltage. The manual states that "the driven internal electrode configuration shown below is simple and provides the maximum X, Y and Z travel range", so it would seem as though Z manipulation should be possible. Please tell me if I have misinterpreted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Out5 with -10 volts at its input becomes -250 volts DC. This sets the bias point and prevents any of the AC drives from creating any net positive signal. The manual says

> *Care must be taken not to apply positive voltages to the internal
> electrode since this can lead to depolarisation.*

So you have -250 volt on the inner electrode and that's all it says. If in doubt set In5 to -10 volts because the TD250 amplifier can't produce AC signals bigger than +/- 250 volts: -

> *By applying the full-scale negative voltage to the internal electrode,
> a contraction equal to half the vertical scan range is obtained. This
> method exploits the higher positive electric field strength of the
> piezoelectric material, which is usually five times the negative
> electric field strength.*

Answer (score 0):

I was also confuse with this problem, and finally I consulted their engineer, here's the reply[image]

Comment: Can you change this to a quote with text?